"Page Not Found" with multiple last pages of query
Issue
When accessing the URL https://192.168.1.100/page/30/ in WordPress, I receive a "Page Not Found" error. The query has a maximum of 50 pages, with pages 1-29 displaying correctly. Pages 30-50 show "Page Not Found" in the title but display the correct content. The total number of pages is correct, and get_query_var('paged') returns the correct page number.
I'm using a custom query, because I need to include custom post types and also remove stuff that's already been shown. Also, I tried sending the global wp_query to pagination, no change.
$paged = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

$args = array_merge(
 $wp_query->query_vars,
 array(
     'post__not_in' => $GLOBALS['naytetyt_postaukset'],
     'post_type' => array('post', 'events', 'misc'),
     'posts_per_page' => 10,
     'paged' => $paged
 )
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);

the_posts_pagination(array(
 'current' => max(1, get_query_var('paged')),
 'mid_size' => $sgh_midsize,
 'prev_text' => __($sgh_prev_text, 'mysite'),
 'next_text' => __($sgh_next_text, 'mysite'),
 'total'     => $query->max_num_pages,
));

Environment

Different environment with more posts: 55 pages, pages 1-33 work correctly, pages 34 onwards do not.
WordPress version: Latest
Permalink settings: Resaved
Caching issues: None
Plugins: None causing issues
Theme: Custom coded

Steps Tried

Permalink Settings: Resaved, no effect.
Caching: Verified no issues.
Reading Settings: Changed "Blog pages show at most" from 10 to 50, no effect.
Paged Variable:
$paged = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;


WP_DEBUG: Enabled, no errors.
pre_get_posts Hook: No effect.
Permalink Structure: Confirmed it supports numeric pagination, no limit on page numbers.
post__not_in: No effect.
URL Formation: URLs are correctly formed.
.htaccess: Unmodified, all configurations correct.
Hooks: No issues found.
404 Status: No code or configuration sets the status to 404.
Theme and Plugins: Custom theme, no plugins affecting the issue.

Despite extensive debugging, the issue persists. All configurations and settings appear correct, and no evident errors or causes are identified within the theme or plugins. The problem appears when a specific page threshold is reached, with no clear reason why pages beyond a certain number return a "Page Not Found" status despite correct content display.
If anyone can point me to the right direction, I would greatly appreciate it.

Is this intended to be the main query for the page you're displaying it on?

Hey Chris, yes, it's the main query.
Just using $wp_query doesn't work, either.

You mentioned in step 6 that you've tried hooking to pre_get_posts - that's the only correct way to replace the main query, so could you replace your code above with the code you used in that step?  No point troubleshooting why doing something the wrong way doesn't work, let's focus on the right way.
